# git-svn запомнить логин/пароль

Tags: git, git-svn, tortoise-git

Есть репозиторий svn на корпоративном внутрисетевом сервере. Менять его на git, hg или любую другую DVCS начальство не собирается.

Локально использую git (Windows) через git-svn. Возвращаться обратно на svn также не собираюсь.

Проблема: git-svn каждый раз запрашивает логин и пароль к репозиторию.

**Вопрос**: как сделать так, чтобы авторизация не запрашивалась каждый раз, или, хотя бы, запрашивался только пароль?

Устроит и частичное решение (только для консоли или только для gui TortoiseGIT). Также устроит решение с хранением пароля в открытом виде. Сервер локальный, извне не виден. Пароли ставились только по тому, что у TortoiseSVN не работает "запомнить пароль" если пароля нет.

Имя локальной учетки не совпадает с логином в репозиторий.

Пробовал настроить git credentials, но не разобрался. Возможно git-svn их не использует.

PS Может кому-нибудь полезно. В Win10 настройки svn хранятся не в `~\.subversion`, а в `~\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\`

Comment: Есть тут один товарищ, он бы пришёл и вас наругал, что отказываетесь от кошерного SVN. Но он не сможет, потому что он постоянно в бане. :)

Comment: пробовали склонировать с логином и паролем `git svn clone https://server/svn/repo2 --username=xxx` и почистить кэш  %HOMEPATH%\.subversion\auth\svn.simple ?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, сейчас попробовал. Не помогло

Comment: @ГерманБорисов попробуйте два варианта, прежде забекапившись: 1) почистить ~/.subversion целиком; 2) почистить каталог auth целиком.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko, очистку ~/.subversion я делал прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: Варианты из этого вопроса вы конечно же видели и пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/q/605519/2790048

Comment: а также [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2899209/2790048) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2599281/2790048).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, видел и пробовал. У меня не сохраняется логин

Comment: Я очень давно пользовался `git-svn`, но что если пароль и логин прописать в URL? Типа `git svn clone https://user:pass@server/svn/repo2  ?

Comment: @Герман, я уже написал было письмо знакомому англоязычному эксперту, но подумал, что может быть путь проще. Можно просто опубликовать вопрос ещё и на en.SO. Как у вас с английским? Если нужно, могу помочь перевести вопрос и потом ответ обратно на русский.

Comment: Почему я сам не могу перевести и опубликовать на en.SO: будут уточняющие вопросы, а я на них не смогу ответить.